# Error when displaying nearest neighbors analysis with tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I would like to use the `tmap` library to display my nearest neighbour analysis above. My code is below with a simple plot function to create the map attached but like I said i want to display this using `tmap`

[image]

```
#Identify the tract centroids
        tract_cent <- gCentroid(dfw1, byid=TRUE)
        tract_centspdf<- SpatialPointsDataFrame(gCentroid(dfw1, byid=TRUE), dfw1@data, match.ID=FALSE)
        
        # Neighbors for k = 1
        
        # Find the set of the k nearest neighbors for each tract
        tract_knn1 <- knearneigh(tract_centspdf, k=1)
        
        #create a column with index number 
        dfw1@data  <- dfw1@data  %>% mutate(id = row_number())
        
        # add IDs to spdf data frame
        dfw1$nn= tract_knn1$nn
        summary(dfw1$nn)
       

        # Converts the knn object into a neighbors list 
        tract_knb1 <- knn2nb(tract_knn1)
      
        
        # Plot the neighbors
        par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
        plot(dfw1, border="gray", lwd=4)
        plot(tract_knb1, coords=tract_cent@coords, arrows=TRUE, length=0.08,
             lwd=2, col="purple", pch=16, cex=0.75, add=TRUE)
        title(main="K Nearest Neighbors\nk = 1", line=-3)

#TMAP code 

   tm_shape(dfw1) +
tm_polygons("Consumer", title="Fiber Optic availability") +
tm_shape(centroids)+
tm_dots()
 tm_shape(tract_knb1, tract_centspdf)+
tm_markers(arrows=TRUE, length=0.08,
           lwd=2, col="purple", pch=16, cex=0.75, add=TRUE)
   tm_style_white()
```

> Error in rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :    attempt to replicate
> an object of type 'S4'

Comment: click  "BASIC PLOT"  at beginning of post to see the map I referenced

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, questions should include a specific programming issue where you expected an outcome but got something else, like an error. It's not a code service or tutorial.